# How to find node that doesn't have root in database binary tree

Tags: sql, sql-server

I design database for binary plan(MLM).

```
TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_left_down` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_right_down` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_adviser` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

`user_id` is root node(primary key).
`user_left_down` and `user_right_down` is a left node and right node of user_id

```
               `user_id`
               /      \
  `user_left_down`     `user_right_down`
```

the question is how can I find the user_id that doesn't have upper node and `user_adviser` = @some_id

This was I think

```
first_query = ( SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_adviser = @some_id )

foreach( first_query as @id)
   IF ( SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_left_down = @id OR user_right_down = @id) == NULL
       // this @id doesn't have upper node

return all @id that doesn't have upper node
```

example data in database

```
user_id || user_left_down || user_right_down || user_adviser
   1             2                NULL             smith
   2             3                 4               smith
   3            NULL              NULL             john
   4            NULL               9               robert
   5             8                 11              smith
   6            NULL              NULL             robert
   7            NULL              NULL             smith
  ...           ...               ...              ...
```

Data in tree view

```
             1                      5                6           7
          /      \              /      \
         2                    8         11
      /      \
     3        4
               \
                9
```

Node that doesn't have upper node is 1 , 5 , 6 , 7

Example input

```
sql = "... WHERE user_adviser = "smith" ..."
```

output will return

```
   user_id
      1
      5
      7
```

(because 1,5,7 have user_adviser = "smith" and doesn't have upper node)

How will I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above pseudo code translates to the following SQL server query

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/UGJIP8569)**</kbd>

```
create TABLE [user] (
  [user_id] int NOT NULL,
  [user_left_down] int DEFAULT NULL,
  [user_right_down] int DEFAULT NULL,
  [user_adviser] varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
)
;
insert into [user] values
 (1, 2  ,NULL,'smith')
,(2, 3  , 4  ,'smith')
,(3,NULL,NULL,'john')
,(4,NULL, 9  ,'robert')
,(5, 8  , 11 ,'smith')
,(6,NULL,NULL,'robert')
,(7,NULL,NULL,'smith');

select U.user_id
FROM  [user] U
left join [user] u2 on U.user_id =u2.user_left_down or U.user_id= u2.user_right_down
where
u2.user_id is null
 and u.user_adviser = 'smith'
```

**Explanation:**
the part below finds all root nodes

```
left join [user] u2 on U.user_id =u2.user_left_down or U.user_id= u2.user_right_down
    where
    u2.user_id is null
```

and the last where clause finds the correct node which has the adviser as smith

```
 and u.user_adviser = 'smith'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please use this - ** We need to use RIGHT JOIN.

```
SELECT T1.user_id
FROM  [user] U
RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM [user] T1 WHERE t1.user_adviser = 'Smith' ) T1
ON (u.user_left_down=T1.user_id or u.user_right_down=T1.user_id )
WHERE u.user_id IS NULL

user_id
-----------
1
5
7

(3 rows affected)
```